# Python. Построить график гиперболы и сохранить

Tags: python, график

Добрый день! Необходимо построить график математической функции(y=f(x))(Например, гиперболы). Сейчас пытаюсь реализовать на sympy и Wand:

```
from wand.font import *
from wand.image import *
from wand.drawing import *
from wand.color import *
from wand import *
from sympy import *
def o2n(x,y):
    centerx = 500
    centery = 450
    y = -y*10+centery
    x = x*10+centerx
    print(x, y)
    return x,y
x = symbols('x')
inp = input()
slv = sympify(inp)
print(slv)

with Drawing() as draw:
    with Image(width=1000, height=900,background=Color('white')) as image:
        old = 0
        draw.line((0,image.height//2),(image.width,image.height//2)) #Ось Х
        draw.line((image.width//2,0),(image.width//2,image.height)) #Ось Y
        for j in range(-600,600):
            try:
                y=float(slv.subs(x, j))
                y2=float(slv.subs(x, j+1))
                draw.line(o2n(j,y),o2n(j+1,y2))
            except:
                pass
        draw(image)
        image.save(filename='result.png')
```

Но получается не точно(Линии гиперболы сливаются с осями координат). Есть ли у кого-нибудь идеи по этому поводу? Думал на numpy, но не нашёл, как всё это сохранить в картинку(Желательно, jpg)

Comment: А matplotlib чем не устроил?